# Can I download DLC onto more than one PlayStation 3?

Tags: ps3

If I download DLC on one of my PlayStation 3s, will I still be able to download it to other PlayStation 3s? I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your PS3 login (PSN login), and sign into the PS3 you want the DLC on. If you are on your own PS3, download the DLC you want. Then you can go to a different PS3 and log in to the account you got the DLC on. Go to the PSN store, then go to purchases, and once it loads there will be a little blue arrow next to everything you have downloaded before. Click one and then it will download on that ps3. After you get everything you want you can log out and sign into your friend's account and he/she will have it.

It doesn't have to be downloaded on your PS3. You can get it on your friends house on his/her PS3. Then go home and download the DLC on your ps3. You can only have 2-3 PS3 connected with one account.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, however you are limited to how many systems you can use the DLC on

when you do to download DLC onto the PS3 there is a notice before it downloads saying Activating, that's PSN registering that PS3 to download the DLC, there should be a limit to the number of systems you can download DLC but i'm not 100% sure what it is

should also point out that your PSN account can only have a limited number of PS3 consoles activated to it (i think it's 2 Consoles and 2 Handholds, please correct me on this), if you've reached this limit then you won't be able to sign into your PSN account until you deactivate one of your consoles

Answer (score 1):

You can have your PSN account on as many PS3s as you want, but can only have two activated. All you have to do is go to Account Management and Activate/Deactivate. I have my account on 3 PS3s - mine, my dad's and a family member's.

A nice little trick: if both of you and somebody else have your PS3 in the same house, deactivate your account from your PS3, activate it to his and download what you want, then deactivate the account. Both of you will keep all DLC downloaded - the reason being is it saved to the hard drive of the Playstation.

Comment: Hi Michael, and welcome to Arqade. Your answer seemed to have good information in it, but it was hard to read due to the lack of punctuation, capital letters, etc. I've suggested an edit to make it more readable and to remove some of the personal anecdotes that might not fit here. I hope this is helpful, and I hope you stick around and ask and answer many more questions!

Answer (score -2):

you can only play the DLC if you are signed in the user it was downloaded it on. It doesn't matter if you have the content downloaded if you're not signed in to the user name you downloaded it on

Comment: That's incorrect. Almost every DLC piece will be available to any user on an activated system where it has been downloaded.